# How to prove that $1/|z^4-4z^2+3|\le 1/3$ if $z$ is a complex number with $|z|=2 $?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Show
>   $$\left\lvert \frac{1}{z^4-4z^2+3} \right\rvert \leq \frac{1}{3},\, \text{ if } |z|=2.$$

I am sure it is pretty easy and I am overlooking something.

So this is equivalent to
$$3 \leq \left\lvert z^2-1\right\rvert\cdot\left\lvert z^2-3\right\rvert.$$
I know $z^2$ is on the circle of radius 4 centered at the origin in $\mathbb{C}$. So I am now thinking of the distance from $z^2$ to $1$ and the distance from $z^2$ to $3$ to help show the bound is true. I am trying to find the minimum distances of $z^2$ to $1$ for example, and the way I have been going about this is by explicitly looking at the distance and making a function $f(x,y)$ and trying to compute its minimum, but I don't know how to really do this without breaking into cases of $x\geq 0$ and $x <0$ if $z=x+iy$ so I am wondering if this is overkill and if there is another simpler way.

Comment: Do you know how to write your $z$ in polar form?

Comment: I haven't thought of that but I am open to trying that. I am just working through a complex textbook. Thanks I will maybe look into trying that.

Comment: Hint: $|a - b| \ge ||a| - |b||$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that, on $|z|=2$,
$$|z^4-4z^2+3|=|(z^2-1)(z^2-3)|\ge(|z|^2-1)(|z|^2-3)=3$$
and hence
$$\frac{1}{|z^4-4z^2+3|}\le\frac13.$$

Comment: Not sure the inequality follows. It's not true that $|a + b| \ge |a| + |b|$, but you have $+3$ there

Comment: @Mathmo123, I made a mistake before.

Comment: Looks good now. +1 for simplicity

Comment: Are we applying the reverse-triangle inequality to a product essentially?

Comment: @NinosławCiszewski, that is right, $|a-b|\ge ||a|-|b||$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $|z^2 - 1| = |4\mathrm e^{i\theta}-1|$ is a circle of radius $4$ centred at $-1$. It is therefore minimised when $\theta = 0$. Something similar will work for the other factor.

Answer (score 3):

Your inequality is equivalent to:
$$\forall z\in S^1,\qquad |16z^4-16z^2+3|\geq 3,$$
or to:
$$\forall \theta\in[0,2\pi],\quad \left(16\cos(4\theta)-16\cos(2\theta)+3\right)^2+\left(16\sin(4\theta)-16\sin(2\theta)\right)^2\geq 9,$$
that is equivalent to:
$$ 512+9-512\cos(2\theta)+96\left(\cos(4\theta)-\cos(2\theta)\right)\geq 9$$
or to:
$$ 16-19\cos(2\theta)+3\cos(4\theta)\geq 0$$
or to:
$$ \sin^2\theta\left(13-6\cos(2\theta)\right)\geq 0$$
that is trivial.

Comment: Whilst your logic *does* hold, I worry that for a homework-like question, this argument lends itself to being misinterpreted as having false logic. - i.e. your logic is $f \ge 0 \iff g \ge 0$ and $g \ge 0$ is true. But it could be misinterpreted as $f \ge 0 \implies g \ge 0$ and $g \ge 0$ is true, which would be unfortunate.

Comment: Come on, "is equivalent" means "is equivalent".

Comment: Yes it does, and hence there is nothing technically wrong here. But someone less experienced than yourself who glances over this answer would very easily miss that point.